# The action 'create' could not be found for SessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm currently attempting to create a user login page. To do this I'm using Sessions. Whenever I open the login page, it loads, but when I try to put in login information of a user I know exists, I get the error

```
Unknown action
The action 'create' could not be found for SessionsController
```

My routes file looks like this. Also as a note, I'm using teachers as a user class here.

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => 'home#index'
  get    'teachers' => 'teachers#all'
  get    'profile' => 'teachers#show'
  get    'signup'  => 'teachers#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :teachers
end
```

and the sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  module SessionsHelper

    def new
      @session=Session.new
    end

    def log_in(teacher)
      session[:teacher_id] = teacher.id
    end

    def create
      teacher = Teacher.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                               params[:session][:password])
      if teacher.nil?
        flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
        @title = "Sign in"
        render 'new'
      else
        sign_in teacher
        redirect_to teacher
      end
    end

    def remember(teacher)
      teacher.remember
      cookies.permanent.signed[:teacher_id] = teacher.id
      cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = teacher.remember_token
    end

    def current_teacher
      if (teacher_id = session[:teacher_id])
        @current_teacher ||= Teacher.find_by(id: teacher_id)
      elsif (teacher_id = cookies.signed[:teacher_id])
        teacher = Teacher.find_by(id: teacher_id)
        if teacher && teacher.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
          log_in teacher
          @current_teacher = teacher
        end
      end
    end

    def logged_in?
      !current_teacher.nil?
    end

    def log_out
      session.delete(:teacher_id)
      @current_teacher = nil
    end

    def destroy
      log_out if logged_in?
      redirect_to root_url
    end

  end
end
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: why the `module SessionsHelper` ?

Comment: I feel really dumb, but I put that in for the helper class and I meant to delete it here. I completely overlooked it. I took it out and it solved the issue. Thanks so much

Comment: glad that sorted it for you